# Best approach - google maps, nearby predefined markers

Tags: php, google-maps

So I have some predefined markers. I would like users (for free) to be able to search within a predefined radius of there current position for said markers. The markers will be pulled from a database that contains there geolocated location. Would this involve some PHP wizardry trolling through the database looking for results within the boundary. Or would it be better just have a region option where it would only match region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Haversine formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

We use this on all of our client's sites to search for store locations nearest to the search query entered by the customer (usually using Google to geocode their query).  This Google Maps API page shows you how to do it:  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html